# Setup Wizard succeeds but doesn't create

Tags: admin, installation, setup

I followed the easy install procedure

```
guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/zip_install.html
```

and used this software version:

```
Magento-CE-2.1.7-2017-05-30-01-54-40.tar.gz
```

Everything set up successfully, but when I click **Launch Magento Admin** on the success page, I get 404 not found. If I browse to the Magento DIR I do get a home page, but it is just plain HTML (no styles), and all links also result in 404: login, create account, my cart, etc.

Something seems to be missing?

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with URL rewriting.

On RHEL7, I configured the following:

## cd conf.modules.d/

[root@d101nstor01 conf.modules.d]# egrep -i rewrite *

00-base.conf:LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

## vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

AllowOverride All